# Use of the dative on inscriptions

Tags: dative, grammar-identification

On the Bundestag building, the inscription reads "dem deutschen Volke", the German people. It is in the dative case. Why is the nominative case "das deutsches Volk" not used?

Comment: Nominativ would be _das deutsche Volk_

Comment: "Why the downvotes?" I didn't downvote, but I guess that in all questions of type "Why is XXX not used?" one should motivate why XXX should be used. The nominative case would mean "The German people", which would not make much sense in German nor in English. It would have even been better just to ask why there is the dative there.

Comment: Here's an example for a nominative https://goo.gl/maps/vBb8xaYzSs92: "Otto-Hahn-Bau der Freien Universität": nominative name of the building "Otto-Hahn-Bau" with a genitive "der Freien Universität" (building belongs to free university) (could be a dative as well - dative and genitive are indistinguishable - but I read it as denoting ownership by genitive rather than a dedication by dative).  (I'd have thought there's a sign at the Bundeskanzleramt saying so - but didn't find an image)

Comment: Nominative works for buildings as it is quite normal in German to call the building the same as its contents (e.g. Bundeskanzleramt, Deutsches Museum can both refer to the building or the more abstract thing that is found inside this building). Of course, a building could also have a name of its own (e.g. Messeturm - doesn't house the Frankfurt trade fair, it's just closeby).

Comment: @cbeleites: "Dem deutschen Volke" is not a building name (its name would be _Reichstag_ here) but a dedication. Such a dedication could be anywhere, not only at buildings (typically at monuments).

Comment: @Stef, yes of course (as I commented below tofro's answer). I didn't think the "why not nominative" subquestion needs a full answer, but explaining what a nominative on a building does would be a good "bonus info" type comment in addition to the dative explaning answers.

Comment: @cbeleites: OK, didn't see this comment. Just wanted to prevent this thread from getting side-tracked.

Answer (score 21):

For the same reason you use *to* in an English dedication:

> To my father

You wouldn't just put 'My father', since you're telling us who you are dedicating the book to, not what it is.

Comment: Very good. This is the exact equivalent one would expect on a building in America or GB: "To the American/British People", short for [[This building is] dedicated] to the American/British people." Similar to a toast: "To our health."

Answer (score 19):

It's an ellipsis of

> „Dieses Parlament ist **dem deutschen Volk** gewidmet“ *(This parliament is dedicated to the German people)*.

*Widmen* requires a dativ object in German.

See [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dem_deutschen_Volke) for a detailed article about this inscription (unfortunately in German only).

Similar typical inscriptions are "Dem Gedenken an ...", "Den Opfern von ..." usw.

Comment: I have a hard time memorizing dativ verbs, so I try to rationalize why they are dativ. In this case, ```to dedicate``` is dativ it seems because there is an implied subject -  someone must have done the dedication. So, ```This parliament is dedicated to the German people``` becomes ```'We' (subject) dedicate 'this parliament' (direct object) to the German people (indirect object)``` and therefore, ```dem``` is used.

Answer (score 14):

This is what's called a *dativus finalis*

It tends to denote *purpose* and thus means "this is for [the benefit of] the German people".

Latin knew the same notion, an example would be "tibi laetitiae", meaning something along the lines of "for your enjoyment".

A simple nominative wouldn't transport this meaning (rather, it wouldn't transport much meaning on a building).

Comment: "A simple nominative wouldn't [...] transport much meaning on a building" The nominative would transport the meaning "this is the name of the building". So in this case, it would be "Reichstag".

Comment: @cbeleites Well obviously "*Das deutsche Volk*" would be the nominative inscription, which doesn't make a lot of sense to write onto a building.

Comment: -1. Only the Latin case is a dativus finalis, consisting of two datives _tibi_ "to you" and _laetitiae_ "to/for health". Try recasting the Latin in your own paraphrase of purpose: "This for the benefit of you for the benefit of health"?! Note that _tibi_ is the dative of "you", not the dative of the possessive pronoun (which would be _tuae_).

Comment: @sgf I'm not getting your point. Are you assuming *laetitiae* is a dative? And, no, *laetitia* does not translate to "health".

Comment: @tofro ah woops, of course _laetitia_ is "enjoyment". But yes, I'm assuming _laetitiae_ is a dative. Genitive would make no sense, and two datives are required for a dativus finalis.

Comment: @tofo: well, a building cannot be or contain a people - but it can house other institutions and can then be labeled in the nominative. So even aside from the trivial solution of giving a name in the nominative, there are lots of nominative names on buildings. But you are right, not all nominatives are suitable for writing on buildings. And Das deutsche Volk would not be a suitable one. Whereas Bundestag could theoretically appear as a label in nominative, genitive or dative (cannot thing of an accusative right now)

Answer (score -1):

it's the same dative case as:

**to whom it may concern ...**

Comment: No, it's not. The dative in *to whom it may concern* is caused by the preposition "to". That is something entirely different than a free-standing dative. Note it's not "zu dem deutschen Volke" on the Reichstag.

Comment: I disagree. I have chosen this term to show that  "dem deutschen Volke (gewidmet)" is an abbreviation like "to whom it may concern ..." . Whom is the pronoun for  Volk, Vater and others ...The verb in this case might be "addressed" and could even be: the next  song is "dedicated" to whom it may concern. The difference is only that in German you had to use the accusative (an wen, für wen).